# JS - Shouldn't this be written better? One function vs multiples?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I have a tweet stream where new tweets are added at the top and the older ones pushed down. You can click on the entire tweet and a panel slides down to reveal, "reply", "retweet", "favorite" etc. The panel is added to each new tweet added in the stream.

The code below works. Shouldn't this be better written so that only one call is being made? Or, as a new tweet is added. would I just have to add to the code with div#tc4, ul#tb4 etc?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div#tc1").click(function () {
        $("ul#tb1").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("div#tc2").click(function () {
        $('ul#tb2').slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("div#tc3").click(function () {
        $('ul#tb3').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

Added Markup:

```
<div id="tc1" class="tweetcontainer">
<div class="avatarcontainer">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="tweetheader">
    <div class="name">
      <h1>John Drake</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="tweethandle">
      <h2>@Drakejon</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="tweettime">10m</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Exceptional Buys Ranger To Give Monitoring Shot In The Arm To Its 'DevOps' Platform <a href="http://tcrn.ch/11m3BrO">http://tcrn.ch/11m3BrO</a> by <a href="#">@sohear</a> </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <!-------------Tool Bar -------------------------------->
<ul id="tb1" class="toolbar">
  <li><a class="reply" href="#"><span>reply</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="retweet" href="#"><span>retweet</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="favorite" href="#"><span>favorite</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="track" href="#"><span>track</span></a></li>
  <li><a class="details" href="#"><span>details</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please post your markup, surely there is no need to use IDs in this case.

Comment: Markup has been added. Each new tweet added to the stream would need it's own id right? If there is a better way of coding this then I would love to know.

Comment: Here is the code working http://jsfiddle.net/tmoura/vckFb/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend separating your javascript from your detailed page function. The best way to do this is to put the retweeting panel *inside* the tweet container, then you don't even need to give it an id at all or encode in the javascript information about your html structure and ids. You can then just do:

```
$('.tweetcontainer').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(event.target).is(':descendantof(.toolbar)')) {
       //ignore all clicks within the toolbar itself
       return;
    }
    $(this).find('.toolbar').slideToggle();
});​
```

It's *that* easy! [See it in action in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErikE/jZJ6U/).

Now you can add as many tweet containers as you want to your page--and your javascript doesn't have to change one bit. Other solutions that require knowledge of specific ids linking to specific ids are suboptimal.

Note the `descendantof` pseudo-selector is custom (see the fiddle to find out how it works). Also, since you didn't provide any css, I had to choose some--it was quick so don't expect much. (Aww heck I just saw you updated your question to provide a  jsFiddle with css giving a far prettier result--but I won't change mine now.) I did have to add a class to the actual tweet itself, but there is probably a better way to style it.

And if you want a click on the displayed toolbar itself (outside of a link) to allow collapsing the toolbar, change the code above to `:descendantof(a)`.

If you don't want to change your page layout, another way to it is to encode the information about the linkage between html parts in the html itself using a `data` attribute. Change your tweetcontainer div to add a `data` attribute with a jQuery style selector in it that will properly locate the target:

```
<div class="tweetcontainer" data-target="#tb1">
```

You don't really have to remove the id if you use it elsewhere, but I wanted you to see that you don't need it any more. Then on document.ready:

```
$('.tweetcontainer').click(function () {
   $($(this).data('target')).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Here is [another jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErikE/Z3JBQ/) demonstrating this alternate technique (though it less elegant, in my opinion).

Last, I would like to mention that it seems possible you have a little bit of "div-itis". (We have all been there.) The toolbar anchor elements have unnecessary spans inside of them. The tweet name `h1` element is inside a div, but could just be an `h1` with class="name" instead.

In general, if there is only a single item inside a div and you can change your stylesheet to eliminate the div, then the div isn't needed. There are an awful lot of nested divs in your html, and I encourage you to remove as many of them as you can. Apply style to the other block elements you use and at least some, if not many, won't be needed.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer with the explanation. Just writing the code out doesn't help the OP without explanation. The spans were there as I was using a sprite for the toolbar. Again thank you.

Comment: I tried your second option in the fiddle. When you copy the html code and past it in below. The top one opens but no longer the lower. I changed the data target to #tb2 and that didn't change. Your first example works perfectly and that's the one I'll be going with.

Comment: The second style works fine, too. You just have to change the id and the reference to the id--two places. I updated the fiddle for you. Also, the first one does not need `.closest('.tweetcontainer')` at all--I updated the fiddle too.

Comment: Actually, you could have done this without moving the toolbar inside, just by using `$(this).next().slideToggle();`. And it would have been a little simpler, since no need to exclude the toolbar from rollup clicks.

Comment: Added your new code and also cleaned up the div-itis I was having a little more.  http://jsfiddle.net/tmoura/Z3JBQ/5/

Comment: Tony, You don't even need the `data` stuff-- just use `$(this).next().slideToggle('fast');`! Could you update your links to go to images that can be loaded, so I can see what the toolbar looks like?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20946/discussion-between-tony-and-erike)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest (though currently untested):

```
$('div[id^="tc"]').click(function(){
    var num = parseInt(this.id.replace(/\D+/g,''),10);
    $('#tb' + num).slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Though given that you don't need the `num` to *be* a number (it'd be fine as a string), you could safely omit the `parseInt()`.

Comment: Interesting that two answers (both up-voted) have since been down-voted without explanation. I wonder why..?

Comment: It wasn't me, but I suspect that the downvoters might have an objection to slicing and dicing to drive function. This is making ids serve two functions instead of one, and leads to brittle code that depends on things being in a certain format. See my answer for how to unlink the javascript from the html entirely, using only the "tweetcontainer" class to drive all behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can write this code much more compactly like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 1; i < 3; i++) {
        $("div#tc" + i).click(function() { $("ul#tb" + i).slideToggle("fast"); } );
    }
});
```

Comment: so to understand correctly. As each new tweet is added the click is looking for div#tc and ul#tb. It then applies the toggle to them?

Comment: No, wanted more clarification of the understanding before I did.

Comment: This would never work because a closure is formed over `i`, which will retain the last value it was given in the `for` loop, making all the tweet containers operate on the very last toolbar.